# Flutter:Question regarding named and initial route

Tags: android, mobile, flutter, flutter-layout

If I am using named routes and initial routes ,home parameter cannot be used so does that mean I will have to create the Scaffold and Material App Widget on each new screen I create of the app?

Answer (score 0):

no, you dont. given the example

```
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: 'inicio',
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        'tabs': (BuildContext context) => TabsPage(),
        'eventos': (BuildContext context) => EventosPage(),
        'agenda': (BuildContext context) => AgendaPage(),
        'sobre': (BuildContext context) => SobrePage(),
        'palestrantes': (BuildContext context) => PalestrantesPage(),
        'inicio': (BuildContext context) => InicioPage(),
        'hoteis': (BuildContext context) => HoteisPage(),
        'restaurantes': (BuildContext context) => RestaurantesPage(),
        'info': (BuildContext context) => InfoPage(),
        'homeParticipante': (BuildContext context) => HomeParticipante(),
        'qr': (BuildContext context) => QrPage(),
      },
      title: 'Siepex App',
    );
  }
```

each of the routes return a widget(usually a Scaffold) tha will be mounted on the materialApp as a child.